# How long I can cache tokens and does Azure SDK cache tokens?

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity

With reference to [Azure Managed Service Identity docs for AppServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?context=azure%2Factive-directory%2Fmanaged-identities-azure-resources%2Fcontext%2Fmsi-context&tabs=dotnet) I have below questions.

1. If I use REST API to get the access token, how long I can cache that token before getting new token for the same resource?
2. There is an Azure SDK also to get the token; Does that cache tokens internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. If I use REST API to get the access token, how long I can cache that
>    token before getting a new token for the same resource?

The lifetime of the access token depends on what you set for your Tenant. And [in default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#access-tokens), it's an hour. But for the Managed Identity Service Principals, it does not support to configure the token lifetimes, so it's still the default time: an hour.

> Note that currently we do not support configuring the token lifetimes
> for Managed Identity Service Principals.

You can get more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes).

> 2. There is an Azure SDK also to get the token; Does that cache tokens internally?

The Azure SDK just provides the way to get the token and you need to keep it yourself. The SDK will not keep it.